# Keytool Signing Problem: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: java, android, google-maps, keystore, keytool

I am trying to sign the release version of my Android app (debug was signed fine) for the Google Maps API:

```
keytool -list -alias cancertrials -keystore /Users/syalam/Documents/workspace/Cancer_Trials/keys/release -storepass android -keypass cancertrials
```

But I get the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

I am positive the password is correct, because when I try to export my app in Eclipse, it asks for the keystore and the password, and I am entering it in correctly.

Not sure why I can't sign this? I need to display Google Maps in release mode (working in debug mode).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't think you have to include a storepass when you're just doing a list.  The storepass encrypts the private key which isn't displayed when doing a list.  Just try this:

```
keytool -list -keystore /Users/salam/Documents/yada/yada
```

Then provide your keystore password when prompted.  If that works then you can try just the keypass on the command line.

You might also want to check and make sure your using the same version of Java.  I don't think that's the problem, but if the above doesn't help try it out.

Comment: That worked great. Wish Google had written this in their docs, would've saved me a headache!

Answer (score 5):

Somehow on windows, the keytool would not accept the password. I only needed the SHA1 password for configuring the client id on the project on google dev console. The following seemed to work for me

```
keytool --list --keystore android.jks --protected
```

This printed the SHA1 keys for all aliases.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with jarsigner on jdk1.6.0.31 when I switched back to 1.6.0_29 jarsigner works correctly. Please be aware of jdk version.

Answer (score 2):

Check your alias name once. Some times your alias is different from  is keytool alias name then it gives the same error.
i.e.

Answer (score 0):

`keytool -list -keystore "Path of the keystore"`

This command will ask for password in `linux` machines, whereas in windows machine, you just need to enter the list keystore.