# Google Maps doesn't work after signed the app

Tags: android, android-maps, google-play, android-keystore

I build and sign my android app. Now I publish on google play but when I install on google play, google maps doesn't work. I read some article about this issue but I dont fix it.

What can I do after signing ?

Comment: doesn't works means any error ?

Comment: When I install on google play, I run app, It gets location but It doesnt show on map. Map doesnt work, It seems gray screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is still an issue. But you needed different API Keys for different keystores.

Comment: I export app and I generate different keystore. But how can I generate different API Keys for this keystore ? My keystore location is : C:\Users\Melih\Desktop\cadi\cadi.keystore . keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Melih\Desktop\cadi\cadi.keystore -storepass android -keypass android doesnt work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262773/keytool-signing-problem-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with Facebook. You have to sign your application with your keystore publish key, because your preveous key is a debug key and it doesn't work after publishing app.

Comment: What I understand, I export my app and generate new keystore file then I generate different Api Key using this keystore then I sign my apps again Correct ?

Comment: I export my app and generate new keystore file, this is ok. But How can I generate MD5 for this keystore ? keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Melih\Desktop\cadi\cadi.keystore -storepass android -keypass android doesnt work. It gives error: keytool error: keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect