# How can I get an Android keystore file's "SHA1 fingerprint"?

Tags: google-play-services, sha1, android-keystore, unreal-engine4

Okay, I need some serious help. So I want to use some Google Play Services in my game that's not yet released. I made my game using the Unreal Engine. I followed [this documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/Android/DistributionSigning/index.html) to generate the keystore file, but I need the SHA1 fingerprint and I can't get it.
I tried following [this website](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/obtaining-sha1-fingerprint-android-keystore/), but I keep getting this error:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

Does anyone know about this error, because I'm beginning to get pretty pissed off with this stupid key stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Android keystore usually has a password (eg. production keystores), when you call `keytool -list -v ....`, there should have been a prompt that asks for the password of the keystore selected. If correct, it will give out the necessary information of that keystore (SHA-1, etc.). You can refer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262773/keytool-signing-problem-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect)

Comment: Oh, I ended up finding a solution. I just downloaded some keystore explorer off the internet, and it shows me EVERYTHINGG about my keystore. Now I'm just confused about the difference between debug and release keystores. The first time I linked my app, it asked me to authorize with SHA1 fingerprint. I used some random keystore, but that's not the one I want to use when I release the game. Does the keystore in my APK have to have the same SHA1 as the one I authorized with? Sorry if I sound super confusing. I've never done any of this stuff before..